# How to spread/stretch textual content over an area?

Tags: wpf, text, stretch, viewbox, spread

In WPF,
how do I spread/stretch content over an area (a wide horizontal area)?

Like this: 
[image]

Here's my current code (from the upper part of the picture):

```
<Grid Width="900">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="sclScroller" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Name="txtContent1" Text="1" />
                <TextBlock Name="txtContent2" Text="2" />
                <TextBlock Name="txtContent3" Text="3" />
                <TextBlock Name="txtContent4" Text="4" />
                <TextBlock Name="txtContent5" Text="5" />
                <TextBlock Name="txtContent6" Text="6" />
                <TextBlock Name="txtContent7" Text="7" />
                <TextBlock Name="txtContent8" Text="8" />
            </DockPanel>
        </Viewbox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a uniform grid you can do something like that.

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="8">
    <UniformGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </UniformGrid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Name="txtContent1" Text="1" />
    <TextBlock Name="txtContent2" Text="2" />
    <TextBlock Name="txtContent3" Text="3" />
    <TextBlock Name="txtContent4" Text="4" />
    <TextBlock Name="txtContent5" Text="5" />
    <TextBlock Name="txtContent6" Text="6" />
    <TextBlock Name="txtContent7" Text="7" />
    <TextBlock Name="txtContent8" Text="8" />
</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for! I didn't remember the "UniformGrid".